# Travelling with two passports

Tags: visas, uk

I'm traveling to London, UK for tourism. I just received my passport from UK embassy with 6 months visa. My passport is about to expire and will renew it before travelling to London. So I'm travelling with 2 passports (one with the visa and one is new), I believe that's fine with the UK immigration. My concern is that the visa has the passport number and never travelled to uk before, is there any problem travelling with passport has new visa and holding another new passport?

(Note: travelling from Saudi Arabia to UK)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a problem. The IO at the border will simply stamp your new passport since s/he is not allowed to stamp expired ones and will write 'VIPP' on top of the date stamp meaning that the Visa is in the previous passport.

Comment: But ,, the new visa never gone through uk border ,, is still fine?